# MySQL JOIN multiple rows of one table to one row of other table

Tags: php, mysql, join, rows

I have two tables:

```
Table 1: Articles (id, name, title, content)
Table 2: Comments (id, comment, a_id)
```

Table 2 contains comments with a_id corresponding with the id field in Table 1, and has several rows for the same article

I used the following select statement:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles a JOIN comments c ON a.id = c.a_id WHERE a.name='$a'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row["title"]."<br/>".$row["content"]."<hr/>".$row["comments"]
```

Security issues aside, this shows the contents for the given article name $a, but gives only one comment when there should be multiple ones. What must I do to get all comments for the given article to show up? And shouldn't $row["comments"] be an array?

The end result I'm going for is displaying one article at a time, and all the comments assigned to the given article. Currently all I'm getting is one article and one (the first) comment, even though there are multiple rows in Table 2 with the same value for the a_id field

Comment: Replace `mysql_select` with `mysql_query`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your fetch in a while loop:

```
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if(!$i)
    {
        echo $row["title"]."<br/>".$row["content"]."<hr/>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo $row["comment"] . "<hr />";
}
```

Comment: But this is for only one article at a time, with only one title and content element. Using a while loop would be for showing multiple article titles and content, but I'm wanting one article showing multiple comments.

Comment: @reformed, then you'll have to only echo the title and content from the first row, and for the subsequent rows, only get the comments. See my latest edit.